# In what coordinate would the Lorentz Force move in the following scenario?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces

If a positive current were moving into the page while surrounded by a ferromagnetic material shell; meaning the magnetic field magnitude at the center of the current is equidistant to it's origin; how would the force generated move?

Comment: I’m a little unclear on what you mean by “equidistant to it’s origin.” Also, you would need to define the orientation of the permanent magnetic field (they’re not all the same!).

Comment: This is more of a thought experiment, so I am not basing this on a material example. Basically, a ferromagnetic cylinder has an electric current flowing through it. I am unsure as to how the poles would form in the cylindrical magnet as described above, but I imagine there is only a select number of ways the poles form in this shape.